# Update Android tzdata files

Tags: android, tzdata

I'm not very experienced in working with Android files but I've seen that in some zones like Turks & Caicos Islands the offset can change from year to year. For that I need to update periodically the tzdata files from Android system to the latest version. I've searched for options but what I've found requested to install an app and I don't want that. I've seen that is only one file starting with "tzdata2013". Is there a way to update this file to the latest version trough a script or something, a much more simple way?

Comment: use android joda time: https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

Comment: @AaronHe Interesting, but if I stopped all the Android updates for my device will this solution still work?

Comment: the tzdata comes with the sdk, so as long as you keep updating the sdk on your app, it should just work